# What do you call this tailor clip in English?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

What do you call this in English?

[image: How do you call this in English ?]

Comment: It is called a *safety pin* (BrE and AmE).

Comment: ***PIN*** (both in BrE and AmE) also "safety pin" 
 

​
- a small thin piece of metal with a point at one end, especially used for temporarily holding pieces of cloth together. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pin

Comment: We called them "diaper pins" when I was a kid, although I don't think I've seen one used on a baby's diaper in 40 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

From Wikipedia

> The [safety pin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_pin) is a variation of the regular pin which includes a simple spring mechanism and a clasp. The clasp serves two purposes: to form a closed loop thereby properly fastening the pin to whatever it is applied to, and to cover the end of the pin to protect the user from the sharp point.

I believe you can call this a pin when it is clear from context that the item is a safety pin. Otherwise, a [pin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pin) can refer to a variety of fastening devices, not to mention other devices unrelated to fastening.

Comment: If they have a curve to them like the [pins in this image](http://ep.yimg.com/ay/yhst-17745174073719/38mm-quilt-basting-pin-10.jpg), they are sometimes referred to as basting safety pins (or just basting pins). [More about pin basting](http://weallsew.com/how-to-pin-baste-a-quilt/) for the curious.